# Displaying image if Validation failed in webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

How would I display images(one or more) icon/image based on the validation failed in Webgrid, Code is given below

the below code is showing without any validation.

```
 @grid.GetHtml(
        displayHeader: false,
        columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column(header: "Serial Number", format: @<input type="text" id="SerialNumber" name="serialNumber_@(item.WebGrid.Rows.IndexOf(item))" value="@item.SerialNumber" /> 
            ));
```

I would like to display icon next to the `<input` if the validation is fail.

I have tried to do something like this:

```
grid.Column(header: "Serial Number", format: @<input type="text" id="SerialNumber" name="serialNumber_@(item.WebGrid.Rows.IndexOf(item))" value="@item.SerialNumber" />**@if(item.SerialNumberFailed !=null) {<div><img src=\"failed.gif\" /></div>}**)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I able to figured out - hope this will help others.

```
grid.Column(header: "Serial Number", format: (item) =>
{
int row = item.WebGrid.Rows.IndexOf(item);
string value = item.Location;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ValidationFailed.LocationValidationFailed))
{
return Html.Raw(string.Format("
<input type=\"text\" id=\"Serial Number\" name=\"location_{0}\" value=\"{1}\" />
<div class=\"input-group\">
    <span class=\"fa fa-chain-broken redcolor\" title=\"wrong Serial Number\" </span>
</div>
", row, value));
}
else
{
return Html.Raw(string.Format("
<input type=\"text\" id=\"Location\" name=\"location_{0}\" value=\"{1}\" />", row, value));
//
}
}),
```